# how to random questions in android

Tags: java, android, random

I'm developing a simple quiz in my android project, and I have created 15 sample questions. I want to randomise the questions, but I don't know how to write the code for that. This is what I have so far

```
package com.adm.kana;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Kuis_Hiragana extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView pertanyaan, salahbenar;
    Button jawab, lanjut;
    EditText jawaban;
    int benar = 0, salah = 0, index = 0;
    String[] soal = {"ぐ ", "く ", "あ ", "ば ", "き ゅ ", "ち ょ ", "ち ", "お ", "ぽ ", "ね ", "わ ", "む ", "れ ", "ぞ ", "し ょ "};
    String[] jawabann = {"gu", "ku", "a", "ba", "kyu", "cho", "chi", "o", "po", "ne", "wa", "mu", "re", "zo", "sho"};

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.kuis);

        salahbenar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.salahbenar);
        salahbenar.setText("");
        pertanyaan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soal);
        pertanyaan.setText(soal[0]);
        lanjut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lanjut_soal);
        lanjut.setOnClickListener(this);
        jawab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_jawab);
        jawab.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        salahbenar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.salahbenar);
        jawaban = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jawab);
        if (v == jawab) {
            String jawab1 = jawaban.getText().toString();
            if (jawab1.equalsIgnoreCase(jawabann[index])) {
                salahbenar.setText("BENAR");
                benar++;
            }
            else {
                salahbenar.setText("SALAH");
                salah++;
            }
        }
        else if (v == lanjut) {
            if (index < soal.length - 1) {
                index++;
                pertanyaan.setText(soal[index]);
                jawab.setEnabled(true);
                lanjut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                jawaban.setText("");
                salahbenar.setText("");
            }
            else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Kuis_Hiragana.this, Hasil.class);
                i.putExtra("BENAR", benar);
                i.putExtra("SALAH", salah);
                startActivity(i);
                onStop();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple. I will explain step-by-step.

**Step 1**

```
String[] questions = {"Question 1","Question 2","Question 3","Question 4"};
```

Add 15 questions like this to the string array.

**Step 2**

Create an object of the Random class.

```
Random randomQuests = new Random();
```

**Step 3**

Generate a random question simply by using the rantInt method

```
String randomQuestion = questions[randomQuests.nextInt(15)];
```

The parameter passed must be 15, so that it can generate random numbers between 0 to 14.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a random index I suggest you use java Random calss

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
randomGenerator.nextInt(size of your array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now If you have stored your question in an array String you can use random function

```
Random rand=new Random();
String[] soal={"1 question","2 Question","3 Question "," 15 question"};
String randomQuestion=soal[rand.nextInt(15)];
```

If you have 15 question then rand.nextInt(15) will provide random value from 0 to 14

Comment: sorry, can you explain me more. i don't know much about java.

Comment: Random is a class provided by java which can be used to generate random number (integer ,decimal number ,etc) when you create a variable of class Random you can use nextInt(number) to get random number between 0 to number-1 [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)